# in scala what is the A in sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B

Tags: scala

I see this method in `scala` `List.sum`

```
sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B
```

now I understand that it expects any `num` argument to be implicitly converted to `Numeric[B]` which means its of `typeclass` `Numeric` However what I don't understand is what is this `A` doing there if the implementation block does not refer to it at all.

the return value is `B`
and the implementation is

```
foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)
```

and `num` is also of type `Numeric[B]` so if return value does not refer to `A` and implementation does not refer to `A` why is it needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be able to act on the contents of the list, which are `A`s.  Therefore, `B` must be a superclass of `A`, which is what `B >: A` means.

(In particular, `num.plus` must accept `A` arguments to match the signature of `fold`.)